# Uncompleted downloads: .part file present

Tags: downloads

I'm facing a problem with downloading zipped files from the Internet:

the problem is that when I download the file, in the directory "downloads" there are 2 files instead of one.

1. First one is '' .tgz''
2. the other one is '' .tgz.part''

and I'm pretty sure that is a download problem. Does anyone knows what this is about?

Comment: Yes, the .part indicates a partial download. It is about incomplete or failed downloads and it can have many causes.

Answer (score 1):

No, that isn't a downloading problem. But rather that's how modern browsers/downloaders download files. Instead of downloading file in a single file, it downloads the file in some temporary files (***.part*** in case of Firefox and ***Unconfirmed some_number.crdownload*** in case of Google Chrome). These temporary files can be single or multiple depending on the server it is connected to and the file size. These parts are generally done to establish multiple parallel connections from a single IP and improving the  download speed.

Consider a file of 1GB is being downloaded. The server allows a maximum speed of 1MBPS. It would roughly take 1024 seconds to get downloaded. But if browser requests server for multiple connections to download a single and if server supports that, file could be downloaded in lesser time. Browser/Downloader will request server for downloading multiple files but with **different starting and ending byte stream**. This way the effective downloading speed is increased and you can enjoy the actual connection speed ISP provides.

Once downloading finishes, all part files are integrated into a single file and part files automatically gets deleted.

Comment: I'm not aware that any browsers use parallel streams for download by default?

Comment: @vidarlo As far as I remember once I observed Chrome doing so.

Comment: Interesting! I was not aware of that :) It appears to be controlled by chrome://flags/#enable-parallel-downloading

Comment: @vidarlo Indeed. For firefox there's an [extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multithreaded-download-manager/)

Comment: That extension does not appear to use `part` files. From the description, "Make sure there is enough disk space. The files need to be first downloaded to Firefox's internal storage."

Comment: @xiota I don't actually use that extension. I found that listed in some online suggestion for alternative for Chrome's parallel downloading for firefox. So, I'm not sure about the extension.

Comment: I think "part" just stands for "partial". I don't know of any web browser that does multi-part downloading using "part" files. Multipart downloading utilities tend to preallocate space and track allocation separately, sometimes in an index file.

Comment: @xiota I remember I read somewhere that it was included in Chrome last year when v64 was released. And people asked to do same in firefox on Reedit.

Comment: @xiota I tried to explain question considering general cases. Not FF.

Comment: The question is specifically about `.part` files. The information you've provided about the "general" case is incorrect if there is no browser that uses multiple `.part` files for multi-part downloading. Your answer is also incorrect in stating that there is no download problem. If `.part` files are left behind, **there likely is a problem causing incomplete downloads.**

Answer (score 0):

As noted by others, **Firefox saves partial downloads to `.part` files**. When the download is *complete*, the file is renamed. This is likely to prevent partial downloads from being mistaken for completed downloads. Other Mozilla-based browsers may use the same naming scheme. Chromium-based browsers appear to use a different extension (`.crdownload`).

It is *not* normal to have `.part` files left over after a download has completed. If you still have `.part` files, the download is either **still in progress** or **incomplete**. Check `about:downloads` in Firefox to see if they are still in progress.

In *some* cases, partial downloads *can* be resumed from within Firefox, but I have found it to be unreliable. External utilities are more reliable. For instance, `wget` and `aria2c` will resume incomplete files when the `--continue` flag is used. The output file should be set to the partially downloaded file. When the download is complete, you will need to manually rename it to remove the `.part` extension.

I have seen **no evidence that any browser has ever used multiple `.part` files for multi-part downloads.** Although there appears to be a Firefox extension that allows multipart downloading, the description states "Make sure there is enough disk space. The files need to be first downloaded to Firefox's internal storage." This *internal storage* indicates that the extension does *not* use multiple `.part` files.

External download utilities, such as `aria2c`, often preallocate disk space and index download allocation separately (sometimes within another file, but with a different extension, *not* `.part`).